# Unable to post using Jquery for nodeJS application

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I am unable to post the data to the server and getting a timeout error. Please see the code below:

### Client side script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#form1').on('submit',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/",
                    timeout: 2000,
                    data : JSON.stringify({ image: "yo", text: "apples" }),
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('Success!')
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                        alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
                    }
            });
            })
    })
```

### Server side script :

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.post('/', function (req, res){

        console.log(req.body);
        console.log('req received');

    });
```

On the server I am seeing the output as

```
    APP STARTED ON PORT - 3000
    {}
    req received
```

Can you please guide me for why I am unable to receive the data ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove the  JSON.stringify in the data prop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from JQuery AJAX request to Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478464/how-to-send-data-from-jquery-ajax-request-to-node-js-server)

Comment: @AmitWagner... I am getting the same error

Comment: What is complete `url`, you send from ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting timeout is that you are not responding to the request. Even if your api does not have any result you should respond to the request, at least with a status code.

```js
res.sendStatus(200);
```

`body-parser` by default only parses requests that have `content-type` of `application/json`. Try adding `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` to jQuery ajax options.

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Body is always sent as an object....don't stringify it!

Comment: If I do not stringify the object, shouldn't I use bodyParser at the server side..?